# Laser scanner & Kinect on mobile based

Tags: navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently I've seen people using 3D laser scanner and kinect together for navigation on mobile based robots. Why wouldn't they just use laser scanner since its better? There must be a reason for it. Does anyone know the reason why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236110/laser-scanner-&-kinect-on-mobile-based/) by [Donovan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27064/donovan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The laserscanner only sees one plane (e.g. 10 to 15cm above the floor). You can't see anything on the floor (in the worst case you drive down some stairs) and also other objects as a table are invisible (you only see the legs).

The kinect also provides denser data that can be merged into a 3d representation that is easier to understand for humans than a 2d map. The images also contain more information (e.g. texture) so that the mapping can be more accurate (imagine a long corridor with posters on the wall. The laserscanner will fail but in combination with 2d images, the robot can still localize well).

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0